# Download corresponding file too RecyclerView row

Tags: android, json

I need help with a programming part in Android Studio.

I have a RecyclerView corresponding to a json array from my database. In this array are some informations given to fill the RecyclerView. Every json object has an URL for a corresponding file on a webserver too. 
At this part I need your help. I need to fetch the URL from every json object and download the corresponding file to the device and set it to the RecyclerView row.

The URL in the json has the name: `download_url` (not in my code at the moment but in the json array.

The download state should be shown in the status bar with a progress view (I need to add some informations like the name to the notification). When the user clicks the row the PDF file should be shown in a PFD viewer. 
The next thing is to delete these files from device. They should be deleted automatically if the user refreshs the RecyclerView and the given json don't has the file anymore.
The URL has the filename at the the end corresponding to the file on the server. 
Thanks for your idea's. I'm a beginner and try to give my best to learn a lot from tutorials but this question is very hard and specific for me.

This is my Adapter:

```js
public class PlansAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlansAdapter.MyPlanHolder> {

    private List<Plans> planList;
    private final Context customContext;

    public class MyPlanHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView planTitle, planType, planDate;

        public MyPlanHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            planTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.planTitle);
            planType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.planTyp);
            planDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.planDate);
        }
    }

    public PlansAdapter(List<Plans> planList, Context customContext) {
        this.planList = planList;
        this.customContext = customContext;
    }

    @Override
    public MyPlanHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.plans_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyPlanHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyPlanHolder holder, int position) {

        final Plans plan = planList.get(position);

        // Format timestamp to date
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = null;
        String resultDate = null;

        try {
            date = fmt.parse(plan.getPlanDate());
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            resultDate = fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.planTitle.setText(plan.getPlanTitle());
        holder.planType.setText(plan.getEatingPlanType() + " " + plan.getTrainingPlanType());
        holder.planDate.setText("resultDate);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return planList.size();
    }
}
```

This is my Request.class where I get the json Object:

```js
public class PlansRequest extends StringRequest {
    public static final String PLANS_REQUEST_URL = "http://hiddenwebserver.de/de/json";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public PlansRequest(String loginEmail, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, PLANS_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("loginEmail", loginEmail);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

This is where I set the RecyclerView on my Fragment:

```js
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);

       // Get Refresh Layout
       swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.training_swiperefresh);

       // Connectivity manager for network check
       final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


       // Change color for the refresh layout
       swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.rgb(99, 195, 195));


       swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
           @Override
           public void onRefresh() {
               // Check if network connection exists
               if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                       connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                   // Get plans data from web
                   getPlansData();
               } else {
                   // Error message if internet connection is not available
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.noInternetConnection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       });

       trainingRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.training_recycler_view);

       pAdapter = new PlansAdapter(planList, getContext());
       RecyclerView.LayoutManager pLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

       trainingRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(pLayoutManager);
       trainingRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
       trainingRecyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);

       preparePlansData();

       return view;
 
 }
```

This is where I prepare the data from the json array:

```js
private void preparePlansData() {

    // Connectivity manager for network check
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Check if network connection exists
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

        // Get shared preferences
        SharedPreferences plansPreferenceData = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("plansData", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (plansPreferenceData.contains("plansPreferenceData")) {
            String plansData = plansPreferenceData.getString("plansPreferenceData", "").replace("\"success\":true,", "");
            // Remove success string from jsonResponse
            //plansData.replace("success\":true,", "");
            Log.d("plansData", "Result:" + plansData);

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Plans>>(){}.getType();
            Map<String, Plans> myPlansMap = gson.fromJson(plansData, type);

            planList.addAll(myPlansMap.values());

            // Notify data changes
            pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Now we call setRefreshing(false) to signal refresh has finished
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        } else {
            getPlansData();
        }
    } else {
        // Error message if internet connection is not available
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.noInternetConnectionOnStart), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is actually irrelevant to the question. Besides that you could use the android `DownloadManager` and set `IntentFilter`'s to get notified if the download is done.

Comment: And how to download these files from my given json? I'm a beginner and the code up there is from tutorials so I realy don't know how to do this

Comment: By the way this don't answering my question how to set a dowloaded file (with a DownloadManager you said) to a RecyclerView row